# How can I change the elevation (z-index) of the back button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use a Stack, DraggableScrollableSheet, and a BottomAppBar in my code.
The AppBar has elevation of 0, and a transparent background.
The Scaffold has extendBodyBehindAppBar set to true.

The problem i'm facing is, the back button is visible on top of the DraggableScrollableSheet when it's dragged all the way up.

My question is, how can I put it in it's expected place, under the DraggableScrollableSheet?

Thanks...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Stack:

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: BackButton(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (context, scrollController) => SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: scrollController,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 1000,
            ),
          ),
          initialChildSize: .1,
          minChildSize: .1,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

If you want the red container to go all the way up to the top, you can remove the `SafeArea` on the `Stack` and use it around the `BackButton` instead.

You can also replace the `BackButton` in the above example with

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: BackButton(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
)
```

but in that case I would advise you to wrap it with a `SizedBox` or a `FractionallySizedBox` to prevent it from expanding on all the page

Comment: Ok, I may be misinterpreting the question then. From what I understood you want the back button to go underneath the `DraggableScrollableSheet`, while in the design you showed in the second image it is above. My response is for displaying the back button under the `DraggableScrollableSheet`.  If that is not the effect you want, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Could you share the snippet of your code that produces the unexpected result by editing the question? I am asking this because the first snippet in my answer shows how to display a widget underneath the `DraggableScrollableSheet` and the second goes a bit more in depth if you want that widget to be an `AppBar`. If that is not the desired result, some more information on the scope of the question and how to reproduce might help